# Technologies for audio files storage for on demand mobile app download

Tags: firebase, audio, cloud, storage

Which cloud platform should i use to store audio files for on demand download in a mobile app?

Eg: From the app if the user click a download button, audio files will be downloaded and stored ?

What about Google Drive ,firebase Storage or Dropbox,... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio files are just plain binary files so you can just store them on a simple S3 bucket for example.

Amazon S3 has some benefits:

- easily scalable
- you pay for what you use
- high availability
- trusted by many

But, ultimately, any cloud storage will do.